# heightForRowAtIndexPath is never called though delegate is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I already searched Google the entire day but I just can't figure out a solution for this one.

I am trying to implement a table view with custom cells in my iOS App. I'm using custom cells that display different images and Labels. Everything is working fine except that the Cells are too large for the table view. I know that I need to implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath method but it is never called.

I've tried setting the delegate for the TableView in the nib file and in the ShowPostsViewController in the code but nothing helps. I expect that the problem probably is that the dataSource is set but not the delegate. I can't understand why though.

Every solution I found until now says that the delegate is not set correctly. However, I'm pretty sure it is in my case?!
I'm grateful for any help. Here's my code:

ShowPostsViewController.h

```
@interface ShowPostsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *postsTableView;

@end
```

And ShowPostsViewController.m

```
@implementation ShowPostsViewController
@synthesize postsTableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.postsTableView.delegate = self;
    self.postsTableView.dataSource = self;
    NSLog(@"Delegate set");

    [postsTableView beginUpdates];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        [tempArray addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [postsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSLog(@"Updates Called");


    [postsTableView endUpdates];
    [postsTableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 8;
}

//PostTableViewCell is my custom Cell that I want to display
-(PostTableViewCell*)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    return cell;
}

//This method is not called for some reason
-(CGFloat)tableview: (UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Height Method called");
    CGFloat returnValue = 1000;
    return returnValue;
}

//This method is called
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    NSLog(@"Section Number called");
    return 1;
}
@end
```

I've also got the tableView linked to the ShowPostsViewController in the Interface Builder. 
[image: http://s7.directupload.net/images/130525/6e373mth.png]

Thank you all for your great support.

Comment: In my case, this is method is only called if the tableView 's initial height is greater than 0, I have to set the height to 1 to make it work. Don't know what happens

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are going to kick yourself for this mistake. You have implemented the method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableview: (UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
```

But the actual delegate method should be:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
```

The only difference is the capital `V` in `tableView`. You have a lowercase `v` by mistake.

Try to make use of as much code completion in Xcode as you can to help avoid these types of mistakes.

Comment: If yours row height is constant (1000), you can use rowHeight property instead method of delegate. If you will calculate row height you should do it before the table is drawn.

Comment: @stosha You should have made this comment on the question, not my answer.

Comment: @Stosha: I know an I tried that. Thanks for your answer. I want different heights for different cells though.